# Preserve null on mapping - don't create default for type

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

How can I get AutoMapper to keep null from the source?

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.prop1, opt => opt.AllowNull())
    .ForMember(m => m.prop1, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(null))
    .ForMember(m => m.prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.prop1))
).CreateMapper();
```

prop1 is a nullable, e.g. `string[]`

I always get the default for the type.

Comment: prop1 is an collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The automapper documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html#handling-null-collections) reads as follows:

> When mapping a collection property, if the source value is null
>   AutoMapper will map the destination field to an empty collection
>   rather than setting the destination value to null. This aligns with
>   the behavior of Entity Framework and Framework Design Guidelines that
>   believe C# references, arrays, lists, collections, dictionaries and
>   IEnumerables should NEVER be null, ever.

You can change it using `AllowNullCollections` property:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

`Null` destination values and `null` collections are not allowed by default. You can set this on the configuration:

```
configuration.AllowNullCollections = true;
configuration.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
```

You could also force this via a `AfterMap` configuration:

```
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<MyModel, MyModel>()
   .AfterMap( (s,d) => d.prop1 = s.prop1 == null ? null : d.prop1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(c =>
{
    c.AllowNullCollections = true;
});
```